# Why has the site's icon changed to the general Stack Overflow icon?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Screenshot of RPG.se icon, which become the general Stack Overflow icon]

The icon has been changed. Is this an issue on my side (caching, or something), or on Stack Exchange's side? Or perhaps it was deliberately changed (by mods?)?

Comment: I’m not seeing it. Looks like it’s your side.

Comment: Maybe a caching issue? I don't see it either.

Comment: Tried again with incognito mode (chrome again), and it still have the same issue with different ISP (from Indonesia). Let's see if this will go away in a day.

Comment: It's back to normal. I guess it might be caching issue.

Comment: Note: Technically, that blue icon is actually the icon for [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), not the regular SO logo (and definitely not the general Stack Exchange logo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be part of a known bug network-wide: [Sites' icons appear shifted / wrong sites' icons are appearing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390757/311001) [meta.se post].

Short story: every time a new site is launched, it screws up the icons (for everyone) until some hours have passed and everything's percolated through the CDN.

Comment: Note: This instance of the issue should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I am now seeing a similar issue:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same on computer browser.